# XML Element insert/delete/search using JAXB

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I did simple marshal and unmarshal in JAXB, How to insert/Delete/search element in my xml using JAXB. Kindly provide code snippet.

My input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<comments>
<comment id="id-1">Text1</comment>
<comment id="id-2">Text2</comment>
<comment id="id-3">Text3</comment>
</comments>
```

My Mapping class in java

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "comments" )
public class CommentsNode {

    List<CommentNode> comments;

    @XmlElement( name = "comment" )
    public void setComments(List<CommentNode> comments){
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public List<CommentNode> getComments(){
        return this.comments;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement( name = "comment" )
@XmlType(propOrder = { "id" })
public class CommentNode {

    String id = null;

    @XmlAttribute ( name = "id" )
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

unmarshall code:

```
File file = new File("/Users/vignesh-1200/Desktop/JAXB/sample.xml");
            //StreamSource s = new StreamSource(file);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CommentsNode.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            CommentsNode commentsNode = (CommentsNode) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

            List<CommentNode> childrens = commentsNode.getComments();
            if(childrens!=null){
                for(int i=0,j=childrens.size();i<j;i++){
                    CommentNode child = childrens.get(i);
                    System.out.println(child.getId()+":"+child.getUserId());    
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Childrens Empty");
            }
```

How do i get a particular element in xml using their attribute value. For example, id=2. Kindly help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough in Java 8:

```
commentsNode.getComments().stream()
    .filter(node -> node.getId() == 2)
    .findFirst().get()
```

Comment: Thanks artbristol. Is there any possibilities to work in java 6&7 or shall i go with DOM processing?